# Using NFC Reader with Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, nfc

I've got an ACS ACR122U NFC reader and a Smart Card. I've tried googling but can't seem to find any Native Extensions that will allow me to read/write via NFC.

Would any of you have resources I could read up on?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/ane-lab/) can be used for Android and AIR.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find NFC (beam) native extension http://www.devactionscript.com/free-ane/near-field-communication-nfc-beam-ane-adobe-air-native-extensions-for-android/

Comment: I tried to look at the page via Chrome but it does not display any content. Can you please confirm the website is working?